# Give my friend my steam game?

Tags: steam

I recently bought Metro 2033 from Steam, and my friend wants to play it. Is there any way to share my game with my friend without buying it again? Can I just copy my game folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common and paste it into my friend's folder? Will it appears in my friend's steam library?

Answer (score 1):

Those are just the game's files.  Not the game key to play on a different account.
Steam doesn't *really* support game "loaning" like that, but you could try the family library options under "Steam->Settings"

Comment: Its called family sharing, but yes, that is basically the only way to get this to work, if the game itself supports it, which not all games do.